# Why is my /etc/resolv.conf not correctly populating?

Tags: linux, networking, network-interface, resolv.conf, wlan

I am wondering what causes this to happen. I am using a WiFi connection (wlan0) in my /etc/network/interfaces file. With the settings below I can successfully ping 8.8.8.8 but I am unable to use "apt-get" or "git clone". When I type "route" the results take a long time to populate.

The contents of my /etc/resolv.conf file are:

```
# Generated by resolvconf
search attlocal.net
nameserver XXXX:XXX:XXXX:XXXX::X
```

The contents of my /var/run/dnsmasq/resolv.conf are:

```
# Generated by resolvconf
nameserver XXXX:XXX:XXXX:XXXX::X
```

I don't understand why it is doing this. I usually just get an IP address for nameserver. Any idea what causes this to happen?

Using Raspberry Pi Raspbian Jessie

UPDATE:
If I wait 24 hours the resolv file eventually populates with an IP address but the system fails to execute apt-get update. It will get stuck on the first "get" command. If I ifdown wlan0 and ifup wlan0 the system appears to work fine after. Why is this forced reset needed? How can I avoid doing this and have it connect correctly from the start.

Comment: Are you using any kind of VPN client, are you using DHCP on your WiFi setup?

Comment: To get a start on the issue you should search (grep) through system logs for relevant terms (DNS, nameserver, resolv) to see if there's any warnings or errors.  If you're using a non-Ubuntu variant of Debian you can grep through the output of `journalctl -b0`.  If using a Ubuntu variant grep through (I think) the files under `/var/log/upstart`.

Comment: Are you getting literal X character for your name server or have you redacted that? If it’s redacted, that is an IPV6 name server, is that expected behaviour?

Comment: @juicekebap123 no VPN is used. DHCP is being used.

Comment: @MatthewCline some messages I see in journalctl are:
grep resolv - "no servers found in /var/run/dnsmasq/resolv.conf, will retry"
grep nameserver - "using nameserver 8.8.8.8#53" and  "using nameserver 192.168.1.254#53"
grep dns - "stopped dnsmasq - A lightweight DHCP and caching DNS server"

Anything specific I should be looking for? I am using a raspberry pi Debian Jesse

Comment: @bxm I have redacted that. On working devices I see an actual IP address not in that format.

Comment: Can you show the /var/run/dnsmasq/resolv.conf file?

Comment: @juicekebap123 contents added above

Comment: Looks like you *are* getting an IP for a nameserver, but it’s an IPv6 one rather than IPv4. Maybe there’s something in `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/` that’s enabling IPv6?

Comment: @bxm there is no filepath for that on the device. Is there another directory/file I should check? I don't recall ever enabling ipv6 on my raspberry pi.

Comment: I use dhcpd on my Pi, but overwriting resolv.conf should be a valid workaround for both packages.

Comment: @juicekebap123 i was trying to avoid overwriting the file. I am trying to see why it is not populating correctly. Is this a router issue? I waited 24 hours one day and it did eventually populate but when I ran apt-get update it basically failed to complete the update and was stuck on the first "get". When I ran ifdown wlan0 and ifup wlan0 the system connected fine to the network and everything worked. Why did that fix things? I am trying to avoid doing that.

Comment: @presish There's also `/etc/resolvconf.conf` apparently.

Comment: Might also be worth looking at `/etc/sysctl.conf` and trying to add `net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1`

Comment: @bxm wouldn't it be better to allow ipv6 and figure out why it doesn't work? I found something that says if I want ipv6 kernels enabled I need to add "ipv6" to the bottom of /etc/modules so that it can load at boot

Comment: Possibly, it all depends on your network setup. Your OP was lamenting the absence of a x.x.x.x nameserver so I was offering suggestions towards that. If the situation doesn’t improve when IPv6 is disabled that may direct your investigations.

Comment: @bxm do you know why by default the resolv file says "search attlocal.net" instead of populating right away?

Comment: I'm surmising that's being provided by your DHCP server, which I guess is either your broadband router or something at your ISP.